# First Web API call delay, from Android application

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, httpurlconnection, android-webservice

I have a Web API Asp .Net that can receive an HTTP Post request. I have tested the web service from [Postman - Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en), or other similar application, and all works fine: the web service responses me immediately. But If I try to call the same web service from my Android application I have a problem:

The first call to web service is slow, while the nexts are fast. If I stop to call the ws, and then I retry, for example after 1 minute, the ws response is slow again, and the next ones are fast...an so on.

Here, the code I use for call web service.

```
String wsURI = "www.myWsUrl...";
url = new URL(wsURI);

try{    
    httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpConnection.setDoInput(true); // ?
    httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    JSONStringer requestData = new JSONStringer()
         .object()
              .key("id").value(12)
              .key("frequence").value(1000)
              .key("code").value("ABCAB-0123")
                  .endObject();

    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new  OutputStreamWriter(httpConnection.getOutputStream()));
    out.write(requestData.toString());
    out.close();

    resCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
...

    }catch(){
        ...
    }finally{
        if(httpConnection!=null)
            httpConnection.disconnect();
    }
```

Comment: +1 Interesting topic

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you resolve it? The first call to the same webservice response immediately on iOS, but it takes 10 seconds to get response on Android.

Comment: But this issue disappears if I change to use ip address to make requests.